# how can I normalize the speed of a polygon moving over a series of connected quadratic bezier curves with varying lengths?

Tags: physics, mathematics, movement, beziers

I am generating a bunch of quadratic curves that are connected together, creating an array of curves, and a function which returns the position on the curve for a given time.

```
    quadraticBezier: function(a, b, c, t) {
      var diff = 1 - t;
      return diff * diff * a + diff * 2 * t * b + t * t * c;
    },
```

So I am selecting the appropriate curve based off of current time, and calling that function with the control points (a,b,c) like:

```
      i = Math.floor(timer) % numberOfCurves;

      p0 = curves[i][0];
      p1 = curves[i][1];
      p2 = curves[i][2];

      t = timer % 1;
      polygon.x = quadraticBezier(p0.x, p1.x, p2.x, t);
      polygon.y = quadraticBezier(p0.y, p1.y, p2.y, t);
```

My question is, what is the best way to handle normalizing the speed of the polygon (adding some value to `t`), so that it will be perceived to look like it has a constant speed moving across curves of varying lengths?